# How to stop Bootstrap Badge stripping whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS and bootstrap badges with some embedded glyphicons to display some category information.

When I include the glyphicon in the badge, the text lies a little too close to the glyphicon for my liking.

I have created an Angular JS function to append this white space to the badge text like so:

```
$scope.getWhiteSpace = function() {
  return "    " + $scope.category;
}
```

However, when I try to include whitespace/blankspace (or whatever the correct term is...) in front of the text, the badge seems to automatically strip it.
I need to do it using an angular function because I want to be able to decide if I want the whitespace or not, dependent on whether there is a glyphicon present in the badge.

The only way i've been able to get the effect I want is to include   in the html like so:

```
<span class="badge">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{category}}

</span>
```

What is the correct way to do this using a function? Or is there a simple CSS fix? [I have dabbled unsuccessfully - I am new to this stuff....]

Here is a plnkr which shows what is happening: http://plnkr.co/edit/bCIA8Lw9x2bWzIA55GIP

Comment: Make CSS a class which adds a `padding` to the `span` and decide dynamically whether to add it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty basic issue. You can give `margin-right` to resolve this issue.

You can do it either ways

1) Using inline styling `style="margin-right:10px;"` to the `glyphicon`. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PxcUfLlRfRJgceo6s0pI?p=preview)

2) Give the same styling to `[some class]` and add the same class to the `glyphicon`

Comment: Thanks Masoom - that works really simply and elegant!

Answer (score 0):

use this in css :

```
 .glyphicon-plus-sign:before {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

It already available in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290434/spacing-between-the-glyphicon-and-text)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using &nbsp; you can do it like this:

```
<span ng-bind-html="getWhiteSpace()"></span>
```

And in JS:

```
 $scope.getWhiteSpace = function() {
  return "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + $scope.category;
};
```